# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated works on self but not parentViewController

Tags: ios5

I got dismissModalViewControllerAnimated to work properly on the following setup but am confused as to why it works on self (the modalViewController) rather than the parentViewController.

Here's the setup:

1. I have a UITableViewController with a nav button that calls up a modal view:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.title = @"Root";

        _data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", nil];
        _detailController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(showAbout)];
    }

    - (void)showAbout
    {
        AboutViewController *abv = [[AboutViewController alloc] init];
        abv.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentModalViewController:abv animated:YES];
    }
```

Here's the modal view controller AboutViewController with a toolbar button that triggers a dismiss action to close the modal:

```
    - (IBAction)dismissAction:(id)sender {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

My question is why does [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated] work rather than [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated] ?? Is this new in iOS 5? I thought only the parentViewController is capable of dismissing a child modal view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` Has worked for quite some time. One of the best kept secrets in iOS development if you ask me.

However `self.parentViewController` not working is in fact new to iOS 5. It has been 'replaced' with `self.presentingViewController`.

This causes an interesting problem for code trying to be pre-iOS 5 compatible. Since as you have found `self.parentViewController` returns nil on iOS 5. And `UIViewControllers` do not respond to `presentingViewController` pre-iOS 5.

It leaves us doing something like this:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentingViewController)]){
    [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
else {
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: `[self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]` is dismissing the current view for me. I have 3 levels of modal and want to get rid of 2 of them but this is taking me back to the second level. Any idea?

Comment: @AndréCytryn Yes I have some ideas on that. And I wrote them in an [answer to your question here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12293642/927947)

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using what NJones has said, I would suggest sticking to

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

The reason this will work for all the OSes is stated in the documentation itself:

"The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented. **If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, however, it automatically forwards the message to the presenting view controller.**"

*NOTE: A note about this method in iOS5.0 though. `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated`: method has been deprecated. `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion`: should be used over here instead.*