# dismissModalViewController from another modalViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

So I have a viewController A that presents a modal viewController B.

Then B presents a viewController C.

What I'm trying to do is to dismiss viewController B since I dont need it anymore. Is there a simple way to dismiss B and keep C on the screen as a child of A maybe?

Comment: Not really. If a parent view controller is invalidated, so is its children - you migh need to redesign your UX concept instead.

Comment: hmm, maybe. But anyway its not a the end of the world if I keep that viewController there for a while.

Comment: You can get a reference to vc A from controller B (presentingViewController), and have it present C and dismiss B at the same time.

Comment: This sounds like a bit of premature optimization to me. Is there any reason why you want to get ride of B if this is the view that presented your C view. UX would suggest that if B presented C, B should be some what relevant to C still... rdelmar has the right idea. You should maybe think of using delegates for B and C and allow A to control who is on screen and who gets dismissed.

Comment: @H2CO3 not so sure: For e.g it happened to me I wanted to present a popover with 3 buttons. Each of those buttons was triggering an other modal view for example a mail compose view controller. By the time the mail compose view controller was displayed i didn't want the popover to be shown. Let me know if that sounds bad design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, as many have said, this in a textbook world would/should be a delegate situation. Where `A` presents `B` and `B` presents `C`. Then when `C` is done it tells `B` which dismisses `C` and then `B` tells `A` to dismiss `B`.

I would argue that you are essentially creating a set of modally presented view controllers that amounts to a navigation stack. I would likely implement it as such. Where `A` would be the root view controller. `A` would then push `B` onto the stack and `B` would push `C` onto the stack. When `C` was done it could simply `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` or `popToViewController:A animated:YES` if `A` was not the rootViewController.

Also removing `B` out from underneath of `C` seems problematic. But it doesn't sound like that is set in stone based on your comment:

> But anyway its not a the end of the world if I keep that
>   viewController there for a while. –

That would at least enable a fairly clean delegate setup.

Still it seems like you basically know that when the user is done with `C` they would never need `B` again. If this is the case you can blindly dismiss two or more view controllers at once. And the code for two at a time is fairly simple. (assuming iOS version > 5.0)

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Please note that I said blindly! This code is not forgiving and makes assumptions. For example most obviously that the view controller does in fact have a `presentingViewController` and that that view controller has a `presentingViewController`. If either of these criteria is not met then this code will do **nothing**. This could easily happen if you at any point restructure your app.

So again, if you choose to use this line of code, use it very carefully. And please do consider using a `UINavigationController` for this view hierarchy, or at least delegation.

Comment: I tried adding them as par of the navigationControl but I had issues hiding/showing my tabBar, so I came back with the modal solution.
I'm gonna stick to the `[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` solution.

Comment: @AndréCytryn Fair enough. Sometimes this sort of code is the best choice. A hint for using the `UINavigationController` you can present the `UINavigationController` modally so the entire `UINavigationController` covers the `tabBar`. Either way, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to make this work:

- provide a property on B like "dieOnDismiss"
- implement 'dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES' in B, and forward the message to super
- C optionally sets that property
- when C sends B 'dismissViewControllerAnimated:', B sends the dismiss to super, immediately sends A 'dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO'

Not sure if you can use animated on one transition and have it look right - you may be able to. But if not you can probably just return to A with no animation.

Answer (score 1):

You could try having A conform to a protocol that defines how C is presented, then have B call A to trigger the presentation of C, rather than B being responsible for presenting C itself.  If C can exist independently of B, then A is effectively acting as the "parent" of both.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a share instance that hold a weak pointer to your root view controller (so A here). Use this share instance to present / dismiss C whenever you want from A by using this pointer to A.

**EDIT**

This is to follow up the answer from TimD. In any case in the approach i proposed, C and B will both be presented from A.